# does the word list in tesseract training process require all the words in that language?

Tags: ocr, tesseract

i was training a new language that is not present in Google code and am on the step of making word-list but it doesn't explain what is the list about ....i mean is it the list of words in the training tiff image or is it the list of word in the whole language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation:

> Tesseract uses up to 8 dictionary files for each language. These are all optional, and help Tesseract to decide the likelihood of different possible character combinations.

There are various kinds of dictionaries, you can ignore them at the beginning.

One of the dictionaries is supposed to contain almost all the words, while on of the others is supposed to contain the most popular words. The remaining ones contain other things.

If I knew what language you are creating training data for, I could give some pointers.

But to reiterate: you don't *need* any of them.

See [the relevant part of the documentation](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/TrainingTesseract3#Dictionary_Data_%28Optional%29)